# Firebase doesn't update as expected

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app that makes transactions. Everything reading and writing from and to Firebase works perfectly except for some parts for transaction completion.

In my code, there are two types of payments.

1. Transaction type 1 --- full payment
2. Transaction type 2 --- part payment

In both cases, after payment is made, an update is to be made in Firebase in 3 separate collections.

a) Daily transactions

b) Monthly transactions

c) Yearly transactions

In all cases, Firebase is to get the initial amount in each collection and add the current amount paid.

For now, the Yearly transaction updates work as expected in both cases of transaction type.

However, the Daily transactions and Monthly transactions don't work as expected. The problems are as follows:

When Transaction type 1 is made, sometimes the update on Daily transactions and Monthly transactions is made
as expected. Other times it doesn't. Instead of adding the current amount paid to the previous, it just updates the
current amount made. For example, if the previous amount was 45, and the current amount is 20, the new update is 20 instead of 65.

When Transaction type 2 is made, instead of adding the sum, it starts all over again from scratch instead of updating.
I'm stuck, please check my code and see what I'm doing wrong. Or maybe the bugs might be from the side of Firebase.
PS: All other updates are made as expected when transaction is completed.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime mon = DateTime.now();
DateTime yr = DateTime.now();
String today = DateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(now);
String thisMonth = DateFormat("MMM-yyyy").format(mon);
String thisYear = DateFormat("yyyy").format(yr);
final serviceFee = widget.selectedRide["ServiceFee"];
final service = double.tryParse("$serviceFee") ?? 0.0;
final amountToPay = service - balance;
```

**Transaction type 1**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("DAILYTRANSACTIONS")
    .doc("GH")
    .collection("GHANADAILYTRANSACTIONS")
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
          String day = element.get("Day");
          if (day == today) {
            final bala = element.get("Amount");
            final amountss = bala + service;
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("DAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc("GH")
                .collection("GHANADAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc(today)
                .update({
              "Amount": amountss,
            });
          } else {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("DAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc("GH")
                .collection("GHANADAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc(today)
                .set({
              "Amount": service,
              "Day": today,
            });
          }
        }))
    .whenComplete(() {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("MONTHLYTRANSACTIONS")
      .doc("GHA")
      .collection("GHANAMONTHLYTRANSACT")
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
            String month = element.get("Month");
            if (month == thisMonth) {
              final bala = element.get("Amount");
              final amountss = bala + service;

              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("MONTHLYTRANSACTIONS")
                  .doc("GHA")
                  .collection("GHANAMONTHLYTRANSACT")
                  .doc(thisMonth)
                  .update({
                "Amount": amountss,
              });
            } else {
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("MONTHLYTRANSACTIONS")
                  .doc("GHA")
                  .collection("GHANAMONTHLYTRANSACT")
                  .doc(thisMonth)
                  .set({
                "Amount": service,
                "Month": thisMonth,
              });
            }
          }))
      .whenComplete(() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("YEARLYTRANSACTIONS")
        .doc("GHANA")
        .collection("GHANAYEARLYTRANSACTIONSSS")
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
              String year = element.get("Year");
              if (year == thisYear) {
                final bala = element.get("Amount");
                final amountss = bala + service;

                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("YEARLYTRANSACTIONS")
                    .doc("GHANA")
                    .collection("GHANAYEARLYTRANSACTIONSSS")
                    .doc(thisYear)
                    .update({
                  "Amount": amountss,
                });
              } else {
                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("YEARLYTRANSACTIONS")
                    .doc("GHANA")
                    .collection("GHANAYEARLYTRANSACTIONSSS")
                    .doc(thisYear)
                    .set({
                  "Amount": service,
                  "Year": thisYear,
                });
              }
            }));
  });
});
```

**Transaction type 2**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("DAILYTRANSACTIONS")
    .doc("GH")
    .collection("GHANADAILYTRANSACTIONS")
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
          String day = element.get("Day");
          if (day == today) {
            final bala = element.get("Amount");
            final amountss = bala + amountToPay;
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("DAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc("GH")
                .collection("GHANADAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc(today)
                .update({
              "Amount": amountss,
            });
          } else {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("DAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc("GH")
                .collection("GHANADAILYTRANSACTIONS")
                .doc(today)
                .set({
              "Amount": amountToPay,
              "Day": today,
            });
          }
        }))
    .whenComplete(() {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("MONTHLYTRANSACTIONS")
      .doc("GHA")
      .collection("GHANAMONTHLYTRANSACT")
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
            String month = element.get("Month");
            if (month == thisMonth) {
              final bala = element.get("Amount");
              final amountss = bala + amountToPay;

              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("MONTHLYTRANSACTIONS")
                  .doc("GHA")
                  .collection("GHANAMONTHLYTRANSACT")
                  .doc(thisMonth)
                  .update({
                "Amount": amountss,
              });
            } else {
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("MONTHLYTRANSACTIONS")
                  .doc("GHA")
                  .collection("GHANAMONTHLYTRANSACT")
                  .doc(thisMonth)
                  .set({
                "Amount": amountToPay,
                "Month": thisMonth,
              });
            }
          }))
      .whenComplete(() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("YEARLYTRANSACTIONS")
        .doc("GHANA")
        .collection("GHANAYEARLYTRANSACTIONSSS")
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
              String year = element.get("Year");
              if (year == thisYear) {
                final bala = element.get("Amount");
                final amountss = bala + amountToPay;

                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("YEARLYTRANSACTIONS")
                    .doc("GHANA")
                    .collection("GHANAYEARLYTRANSACTIONSSS")
                    .doc(thisYear)
                    .update({
                  "Amount": amountss,
                });
              } else {
                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("YEARLYTRANSACTIONS")
                    .doc("GHANA")
                    .collection("GHANAYEARLYTRANSACTIONSSS")
                    .doc(thisYear)
                    .set({
                  "Amount": amountToPay,
                  "Year": thisYear,
                });
              }
            }));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that your front-end should not contain such logic. If you want changes in a Firestore document to initiate actions, it's essential to transfer that logic to Cloud Functions. Your front-end's role should only involve getting data from Firestore ([read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) or [listening to changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart_1)), or writing individual documents."

If you have to write to several collections, you should probably just invoke a Cloud Function from you Flutter code and let that function do all the operations in the backend.

There isn't a direct answer to your question, since it implies rethinking the whole architecture of your system. You shall learn about this topics:

- [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd)
- [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Comment: This helped a lot. Though it was difficult to implement. Thanks